# How to execute a command only on the next run?

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

Let's say I have a command `\foo` that I want to execute only on the next run of TeX. How do I create a command `\onceFoo` that does this? (It is also permitted to execute `\foo` if the `aux` file has been compromised.)

Minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\foo{First execution}
\def\onceFoo{This doesn't work.}
\begin{document}
testing: \onceFoo
\end{document}
```

The desired output is

```
testing: First execution
```

on the first run of `latex`, and

```
testing:
```

on every subsequent run.

If the file above (with the correct definition of `\onceFoo`) has been run several times, and the line `new testing: \onceFoo` is added, then the desired output is

```
testing: new testing: First execution
```

on the first subsequent run, and

```
testing: new testing:
```

on all runs thereafter.

---

Motivation: I would like to create a command that clears certain useful files and recomputes them. Normally, this command should be used for a single run to remove corrupted information (or for testing); afterwards, the command should be removed from the source file. However, some users (notably I) are likely to forget to remove the command, since it does not actually break anything--it only produces a significant drop in efficiency, because many things must be recalculated. Thus, I would like a second version of this command that affects only the first run after it is added.

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\foo{First execution}
\newif\ifFirstRun 
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifx\FirstRunTest\@undefined
    \FirstRuntrue
  \else
    \FirstRunfalse  
  \fi
  \write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\FirstRunTest{}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
testing: \ifFirstRun\foo\fi
\end{document}
```

And the same for counting the runs:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\foo{First execution}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifx\runNo\@undefined
    \newcount\runNo \runNo=1
  \else
    \advance\runNo by \@ne
  \fi
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\newcount\string\runNo ^^J
    \string\global\runNo=\the\runNo}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
testing: \ifnum\the\runNo=1\foo\else Run no \the\runNo\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but this does not consider separate occurrences separately. Nevertheless, it's useful and readable; if you post a more elaborate version, please don't delete this one in the process.

Comment: Edited example with counting the runs.